# On the search result all News have a cHash added what comes to an 404 error

Tags: typo3, realurl, tx-news

If i delete the cHash appendix every thing is OK.

TYPO3 7.6.11, news 5.2.0, realurl 2.1.4 with indexed search

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Is the chash correct? Remove the whole index and reindex, does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

Add Below line in your "realurl_autoconf.php".

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
    'init' => array(
         'enableCHashCache' => FALSE,
         ),
```

Comment: This will remove the chash.